# react-native response error code 500

Tags: react-native, runtime-error

I'm encountering a strange issue, when I use `react-native run-android` command on the template project which I've created using `react-native init` I get the following the red error page on the device:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code. I think there is some syntax issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should open your command line and see what error it gives to you. maybe it was syntax error or problem in your packages.you can use [this link](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/401)